# Underscore JS nested each merge objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have two arrays of objects that I'm trying to merge

```
var status = [
  {name: 'status_1', pk:1 }, {name: 'status_2', pk:2 }
]

var to_be_merged = [
  {'status_pk': 1, 'value': 10}, {'status_pk': 2, value: 20}
]
```

desired result

```
var status = [
   {name:'status_1', 
    pk:1, 
    to_be_merged:{
       'status_pk': 1, 'value': 10
    }, {
     name: 'status_2', 
     pk:2,
    to_be_merged: {
      'status_pk': 2, value: 20}
    }, 
]
```

I've tried using nested `_.each` but I lost the scope of the above `each`

```
     _.each(status, function(status) {
        var objs = _.each(to_be_merged, function(x) {
          if (x.status_pk == status.pk) {
            // do something
          }
        })
      })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` should help you. Combine it with `merge` and `where` to merge the two items together.

```
_.each(status, function(item) {  
    item['to_be_merged'] = _.find(to_be_merged, function(other) {
        return other['status_pk'] === item.pk;
    });
})
```

Comment: If this is supposed to be in-place (as requested by the OP as far as I understand), you need to make a few minor changes but the approach is fine in general: `_.map` should be `_.each`, `_.where` should be `_.filter` if you pass in a predicate function. You can drop the `return` altogether because the result is computed by side-effects on `status` only. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @PermaFrost I keep forgetting that `lodash` != `underscore`. :)

Comment: I can totally relate, it's funny how declarative collection APIs use different terms all over the place (comparing Java 8/Streams vs. C#/LINQ vs. Scala vs. Haskell is pretty crazy, nothing is consistent across the board) :)

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly more verbose, but so you can see what's going on:

```
var stat = {
  s: [
       {name: 'status_1', pk:1 }, {name: 'status_2', pk:2 }
   ],
  m: [
      {'status_pk': 1, 'value': 10}, {'status_pk': 2, value: 20}
  ]}
 var merged = []

 _(stat.s).each(function(s){
   _(stat.m).each(function(m){
   var obj = {};
   if(s.pk == m.status_pk){ 
     obj.name = s.name;
     obj.pk = s.pk;
     obj.to_be_meged = m
     merged.push(obj);
   }
  })
})
console.log(merged);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ashilman/db4hnrxz/)